# Validation error when running `npm run serve`

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I recently deleted my old node_modules folder in my project and after running `npm run serve` (vue-cli-service) I get this error:

```
ValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.output has an unknown property 'jsonpFunction'. These properties are valid:
   object { amdContainer?, assetModuleFilename?, asyncChunks?, auxiliaryComment?, charset?, chunkFilename?, chunkFormat?, 
chunkLoadTimeout?, chunkLoading?, chunkLoadingGlobal?, clean?, compareBeforeEmit?, crossOriginLoading?, cssChunkFilename?, cssFilename?, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolNamespace?, enabledChunkLoadingTypes?, enabledLibraryTypes?, enabledWasmLoadingTypes?, environment?, filename?, globalObject?, hashDigest?, hashDigestLength?, hashFunction?, hashSalt?, hotUpdateChunkFilename?, hotUpdateGlobal?, hotUpdateMainFilename?, ignoreBrowserWarnings?, iife?, importFunctionName?, importMetaName?, library?, libraryExport?, libraryTarget?, module?, path?, pathinfo?, publicPath?, scriptType?, sourceMapFilename?, sourcePrefix?, strictModuleErrorHandling?, strictModuleExceptionHandling?, trustedTypes?, umdNamedDefine?, uniqueName?, wasmLoading?, webassemblyModuleFilename?, workerChunkLoading?, workerPublicPath?, 
workerWasmLoading? }
   -> Options affecting the output of the compilation. `output` options tell webpack how to write the compiled files to disk.
   Did you mean output.chunkLoadingGlobal (BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5)?
    at validate (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:135:11)
    at validateSchema (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\validateSchema.js:78:2)
    at create (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:111:24)    at webpack (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:158:32)
    at f (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\node_modules\webpack\lib\index.js:72:16)        
    at serve (C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@vue\cli-service\lib\commands\serve.js:185:22)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @nocware/project-builder-frontend@0.23.10 serve: `vue-cli-service --port 9060 serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Btw I have the same setup on the other machine and it works fine, same version of npm, node and all packages are the same...

I tried all the npm bs...
clear cache, reinstalling everything and still got the same error.

Package.json file:

```
{
    "name": "@nocware/project-builder-frontend",
    "version": "0.23.10",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "serve": "vue-cli-service --port 9060 serve",
        "build": "vue-cli-service build",
        "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
        "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
        "i18n:report": "vue-cli-service i18n:report --src \"./src/**/*.?(js|vue)\" --locales \"./src/locales/**/*.json\"",
        "serve:standalone": "vue-cli-service serve --mode standalone"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@skynet/api-client": "^3.1.3",
        "@skynet/nocware-components": "^1.11.5",
        "axios": "^1.1.3",
        "nanoid": "^4.0.1",
        "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
        "single-spa-vue": "^2.1.0",
        "vcards-js": "^2.10.0",
        "vue": "2.7.14",
        "vue-i18n": "8.28.2",
        "vue-router": "^3.5.4",
        "vuetify": "2.6.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/faker": "^5.5.9",
        "@types/jest": "^27.0.0",
        "@types/vcards-js": "^2.10.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.32.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.32.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "^4.5.14",
        "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.19",
        "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^7.0.0",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
        "faker": "^5.5.3",
        "prettier": "^2.8.8",
        "sass": "~1.32.0",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "standalone-single-spa-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
        "ts-jest": "^27.1.5",
        "typescript": "~4.1.5",
        "vue-cli-plugin-i18n": "^2.1.4",
        "vue-cli-plugin-single-spa": "3.3.0",
        "vue-cli-plugin-vuetify": "^2.5.1",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
        "vuetify-loader": "^1.7.0"
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is not constructive. It's unknown what's the cause and how to fix it. The problem is that package versions have changed after reinstall, and it's unknown why this happened. It's specific to your project and environment, only you know what "version of npm, node and all packages" are. If you don't have a lock file, that's a problem, because it's needed to make package versions reproducible. The way npm uses it is flaky between versions, and again, it's unknown which is yours, so there's nothing to discuss.

Comment: A potential reliable fix is to switch to Yarn 1, since it's more predictable. Run yarn install "the other machine" to generate yarn.lock from existing packages, then copy it to the problematic machine and install packages with yarn from scratch

Comment: node version: 14.21.3
npm version: 9.2.2
Cannot use yarn since the pipeline scripts are configured for npm.
I added package.json file above.

Comment: The error likely means that mismatched webpack version was installed for some reason, which is a dep of vue cli, and which nested dep version is installed depends on lock file. You didn't mention what's the deal with lock file. Do you have it? It's primarily responsible for this, not just package.json. You're supposed to get the same result if you clone a repo from scratch on any machine, at least if node and npm versions are the same. If it was changed in a wrong way, it can be reverted. I doubt that anything else can be suggested at this point.

Comment: Sorry, I also deleted package-lock.json on both machines and it works on one, but not on the other...

Comment: You shouldn't delete it without a good reason. Try to copy it from another one that works, may differ in some way from the one that's in the repo. You need to reinstall from scratch to be sure, i.e. npm cache clean, remove node_modules, npm i.